# problem using page.registerstartupscript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using page.registerstartupscript in my code behind C#. Its like this:

string item1="category1";
string Script = "window.program = '" + item1 + "';";
    Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", Script);

item1 gets generated dynamically from some value in code behind. But its not working. Any suggestoins where I m getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it wrapped in script tags, there's an overload for this in the newer replacement `ClientScript`:

```
string item1="category1";
string Script = "window.program = '" + item1 + "';";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "PopupScript", Script, true);
```

Unless you're on .Net 1.1 I believe, [`Page.RegisterStartupScript` is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I tried what you said....but I m facing some problem ...please look at my answer below.

Comment: @AB - That's normal, something **else** is registering that script for output.  To not repeat `<script></script>` for every single statement, ASP.Net batches them all together.

Comment: I am not adding <script> tag in it..but its adding on its own and also this var _wpmExportWarning is coming attached to it...any idea how  to remove it...or its standard...

Comment: @AB - The `,true)` at the end tells it to add script tags.  I have no idea what's adding the other bits, it's some other control on your page.  Unless you delete that control it's going to show up.  What's it hurting by being there?  It's going to execute the same way whether it's in 1 set of script tags or two, so may as well not waste bandwidth with 2 sets.